# How to access to subsequence of a valarray considering it as a 2D matrix in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, so please be patient with me.
I have a `std::valarray` in which there are `double` elements and I consider it as a 2D matrix.

```
class Matrix {
    valarray<double> elems;
    int r, c;
public:
/* type? operator[](int r) { return ? } */
//...
}
```

I want to overload the `operator[]`, so that I can get a row of the matrix, and after that, I want have the `m[r][c]` access operator.

Is there any way to get a row, as a sequence of `double` using `std::slice` in the `valarray`, so that if I change a value, it is changed also in the matrix?

I've read this definition in valarray:

```
std::slice_array<T> operator[]( std::slice slicearr );
```

My `operator[]` must have `std::slice_array<double>&` as returned type?

Thanks.

Comment: [What is proxy class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994488/what-is-proxy-class-in-c)

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40892890/499359) back in 2016! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `std::slice` and `std::slice_array` is what you're looking for, especially the latter is nothing but a helper type with a very limited public interface. You can instead return an proxy object. Here's a possible example of how to implement that.

```
class Matrix {
    /* ... */

    class RowProxy {
       public:
          RowProxy(std::valarray<double>& elems, int c, int row) :
              elems(elems), c(c), row(row) {}

          double& operator[](int j)
          {
             return elems[row*c + j];
          }

       private:
          std::valarray<double>& elems;
          int row;
          int c;
    };

    RowProxy operator[](int i)
    {
       return RowProxy(elems, c, i);
    }
};
```

This way, you can access the data with two `operator[]`.

```
Matrix m(2, 4); // Assuming the ctor initializes elemens with row*column

m[0][0] = 1.234;
m[1][0] = 2.234;
m[1][3] = -52.023;
```

Note that both `Matrix` and `RowProxy` are missing overloads and proper handling for `const`-ness, and variable names are poor. Also, you might want to think about an out-of-bounds error handling strategy. But it may serve as a starting point for your implementation.

Comment: ok, thanks! In this way I can access the element with m[r][c]. I would ask you, if I want to return an object like a Matrix_row() that contain the "reference" to elements in Matrix object, with the syntax m[], how can I do? Is it possible?

Comment: @Sam This is exactly the proxy object. You can use it like this: `auto row = m[0]`. Then, index the row as `row[0]`. This is exactly the same as `m[0][0]`.

Comment: oooh now I got it, thanks!! 
Just a question. You speak about error handling strategy, It's a good practise to use the valarray exception in constructor without checking size? I mean, in the constructor I pass int r, int c and I create a valarray with r * c elements, but if r * c is < 0 valarray throw an exception. It's a good practise to use that exception or it is better that I check size before create valarray?

Comment: @Sam I think it's fine to do that. Should ideally be documented somewhere. Note, that there is another error that might occur: accessing the array with an out-of-bounds index. This is quite common, you can have a look how `std::vector`  handles that - there are two functions, [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), which throws on out-of-bounds, and [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) which result in UB when called with an out-of-bounds index.